# Selected option alert in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to alert in the web page as per option selected.

But it is not working.

I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").text();
        if{
         selectedCountry == "India"   ;
            alert("You have selected the language - Hindi");
        }
        elseif{
            selectedCountry == "Nepal";
            alert("You have selected the language - Nepali");
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <label>Select Country:</label>
        <select class="country">
            <option value="nepal">Nepal</option>
            <option value="india">India</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have so much syntax errors:

- The condition of an `if` or `else if` statement is after the statement and is within parentheses.
- The else-if statement is `else if` not `elseif`.

Here is a fix:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.country").change(function() {
    var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").text();
    if (selectedCountry == "India") {
      alert("You have selected the language - Hindi");
    } else if (selectedCountry == "Nepal") {
      alert("You have selected the language - Nepali");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<label>Select Country:</label>
<select class="country">
    <option value="nepal">Nepal</option>
    <option value="india">India</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").text();
        if(selectedCountry == "India" ){
            alert("You have selected the language - Hindi");
        }
        else if(selectedCountry == "Nepal"){
            alert("You have selected the language - Nepali");
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <label>Select Country:</label>
        <select class="country">
            <option value="nepal">Nepal</option>
            <option value="india">India</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is just invalid. That isn't how `if` or `if else` statements are structured.

Here's a rewrite:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.country").change(function() {
    var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").text();

    // The condition must be in parens, and before the `{`
    if (selectedCountry == "India") {
      alert("You have selected the language - Hindi");
      
    // Here as well, and `else if` is two words
    } else if (selectedCountry == "Nepal") {
      alert("You have selected the language - Nepali");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<label>Select Country:</label>
<select class="country">
            <option value="nepal">Nepal</option>
            <option value="india">India</option>
        </select>
```

And to be more precise, there is no `else if` statement per se. It's just an `else` with another `if` statement provided as the statement to execute.

The grammar is something like:

> **if** (condition) *statement*
>   
> **else** *statement*

So you can have any statement where one is expected.

```
if (true) foo();
else switch (x) {
  case 'y': bar();
}
```